# Etabs Semi Rigid Diaphragms

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

In Etabs, if I model a building with semi-rigid diaphragms assigned to the floors, the floors will now transfer gravity loads when default meshing is assigned (as compared to rigid diaphragms transferring only mass and lateral loads). If i'm working with a simple model with only walls and floors modeled (no columns), the weight distribution will be incorrect since all the weight from the entire floor is going to the walls. One way to correct that would be to model the columns. Can another way to correct it be to assign a weight modifier of 0.01 to the floors and use dummy beams on top of the walls with assigned gravity loads based on tributary area?

I'd appreciate some insight. Thank you.